# Oracle SQL Query Really slow on a view but not actual table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I was working on a query and using the oracle sql developer really quick made a view to pretty much help me do something I wasn't sure how to do.

Essentially I made the view because a column in our database wasn't required and in some cases the rows were NULL or had incorrect notes written in it. These rows would contain the 'text' column that would have notes like "adjustment to Reebok" account. To properly run my query I needed each row to be able to be mapped to a 'CUSTOMER_NO' value.

Here is the view

```
SELECT t.*,
CASE
    WHEN LENGTH(CUSTOMER_NO) != '6' and text like '%Nike%' or CUSTOMER_NO IS NULL and text like '%Nike%' THEN 'NIK001'
    WHEN LENGTH(CUSTOMER_NO) != '6' and text like '%Nike%' or CUSTOMER_NO IS NULL and text like '%Reebok%' THEN 'REB001'
    ELSE CUSTOMER_NO
    END as CUSTOMER_NO_ADJUSTED
FROM 
gen_led_voucher_row_tab t
```

So this view basically added a new column 'CUSTOMER_NO_ADJUSTED' and now has a column that is 100% filled in. Works as good as I expected it to.

However when I run my original query on this view it just keeps running and never ends/fetches rows. I let it go for 10 minutes and nothing. When I run a similar query on the table itself I get data in under 30 seconds.

Below is the query I am trying to run. I want to basically group CODE_D values into a department name and run the query once with the 'EXISTS' option to see who is an existing customer (has done business with us in XXX months) and then run it again as 'NOT EXISTS' which in theory would produce department values of new business only (Customers who have not done business with us in the specified months).

```
SELECT 
/* CASE statement to rename CODE_D product lines to what the product is. List was provided by accounting in June of 2014 */

CASE
      WHEN CODE_D = '11' or CODE_D = '12' or CODE_D = '18' or CODE_D IS NULL THEN 'Laces'
    WHEN CODE_D = '15' or CODE_D = '16' or CODE_D = '40' or CODE_D = '45' or CODE_D = '50'
      or CODE_D = '55' or CODE_D = '60' or CODE_D = '65' or CODE_D = '67' or CODE_D = '30'
      or CODE_D = '35' THEN 'Custom Soles'
    WHEN CODE_D = '17' THEN 'Custom Heels'
    WHEN CODE_D = '19' or CODE_D = '39' or CODE_D = '49' or CODE_D = '59' or CODE_D = '69'
      THEN 'Socks'
    WHEN CODE_D = '14' THEN 'Sneakers'
    WHEN CODE_D = '89' THEN 'Dress Shoes'
    WHEN CODE_D = '99' THEN 'Other'
    ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
    END as DEPARTMENT,
sum(coalesce(credit_amount, 0) - coalesce(debet_amount,0)) as TOTAL 
FROM 
KPIC_MIKE_METRIC1 a
where ACCOUNTING_YEAR like '2014'
and ACCOUNT not like '4010'
and ACCOUNT like '4%'



and Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    KPIC_MIKE_METRIC1 b
    where   voucher_date >= '01-FEB-13'
    and     voucher_date < '01-FEB-14'
    and ACCOUNT not like '4010'
    and ACCOUNT like '4%'
    and     (credit_amount > '1' or debet_amount > '1')
    and     a.CUSTOMER_NO_ADJUSTED = b.CUSTOMER_NO_ADJUSTED
)



GROUP BY
/*
This GROUP BY statement needs to contain an entire copy of the CASE statement, minus the alias. 
If changes are made to the CASE statement please update this GROUP BY statement 
*/
CASE
          WHEN CODE_D = '11' or CODE_D = '12' or CODE_D = '18' or CODE_D IS NULL THEN 'Laces'
    WHEN CODE_D = '15' or CODE_D = '16' or CODE_D = '40' or CODE_D = '45' or CODE_D = '50'
      or CODE_D = '55' or CODE_D = '60' or CODE_D = '65' or CODE_D = '67' or CODE_D = '30'
      or CODE_D = '35' THEN 'Custom Soles'
    WHEN CODE_D = '17' THEN 'Custom Heels'
    WHEN CODE_D = '19' or CODE_D = '39' or CODE_D = '49' or CODE_D = '59' or CODE_D = '69'
      THEN 'Socks'
    WHEN CODE_D = '14' THEN 'Sneakers'
    WHEN CODE_D = '89' THEN 'Dress Shoes'
    WHEN CODE_D = '99' THEN 'Other'
    ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
    END
ORDER BY TOTAL DESC
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am a novice and I'm sure I might get some better advice on how to properly run this here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What does the execution plan say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You select from the view KPIC_MIKE_METRIC1, and also add an `exists` clause on the same view, where you compare the field `CUSTOMER_NO_ADJUSTED`, which is your calculated field that consists of a case with a `LIKE` condition with a wildcard at the start and end of the condition (thus not using indexes).

If this table contains a good number of rows, then slow performance doesn't surprise me.

I would solve the mapping of codes to departments by storing that information in a table. That at least makes the view more readable and maintainable, and you can add codes and departments more easily.

For performance, I might use a temporary table, but that's mainly because I'm not as experienced with deterministic functions as @mrjoltcola is. :)

Comment: +1 - Actually, mapping the codes to department probably makes more sense. There is no need to use a CASE statement at all.

Comment: Creating a temporary table instead of a view solved all problems! Thanks for the solution! Also thanks to @mrjoltcola for the comments, they were very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is address CUSTOMER_NO_ADJUSTED. You are doing a lot of work to produce the calculated column from a case statement, and then using it as a JOIN column, that won't perform well at all.

Your goal should be to somehow apply an index to joins and criteria on that column if you are going to use it the way you have shown.

1. You could wrap the CASE logic behind the CUSTOMER_NO_ADJUSTED column inside a DETERMINISTIC function, and then create a function based index on that function. DETERMINISTIC is just a way to tell Oracle that for the same input, the function will always return the same output. That way, Oracle can index it. Without that keyword, Oracle will refuse to create a function based index on it.
2. Or a more traditional approach - make CUSTOMER_NO_ADJUSTED a real column that is populated by an INSERT or UPDATE trigger and then you can index that column with a simple index.

The latter is more straightforward and intuitive (and portable).

UPDATE: After reading your CASE statement, I think you would be better served converting it to a lookup table of DEPARTMENTS and DEPT_CODES

```
create table departments (
  id int primary key,
  name varchar(50)
);

insert into departments values(1, 'Laces');
insert into departments values(2, 'Custom Soles');
insert into departments values(3, 'Custom Heels');
insert into departments values(4, 'Socks');

create table dept_codes (
  code_d  varchar(2) primary key,
  dept_id int
);

insert into dept_codes values('11', 1); -- Laces
insert into dept_codes values('12', 1);
insert into dept_codes values('18', 1);
insert into dept_codes values('15', 2); -- Custom Soles
insert into dept_codes values('16', 2);
insert into dept_codes values('40', 2);
insert into dept_codes values('45', 2);
insert into dept_codes values('50', 2); 
insert into dept_codes values('17', 3); -- Custom Heels
insert into dept_codes values('19', 4); -- Socks
insert into dept_codes values('39', 4);
```

Comment: Wow @EvilTeach you are bit quick on the draw editing my post, I just lost a major edit.

Comment: Thanks for editing the answer per the other answers. I really don't want to create any tables or add any columns. Our support provider is really picky over what would break their support agreement with us and  the last thing I would want to do is give them an excuse to back out when needed. I might try this as a temporary table.